# How to save category products progrmtically vai Event Oberver pattern in Magento

Tags: magento

I am looking to assign products programmatically to categories..I have all logic & but don't know in which file need to execute the code.

I want to do this via event observer pattern but don't know which event calls when category is saved.

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a event in your configuration file :

```
<events>
   <catalog_product_save_after>
    <observers>
       <Namespace_Yourmodule_Model_Observer>
           <type>singleton</type>
           <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
           <method>methodName</method>
           </Namespace_Yourmodule_Model_Observer>
       </observers>
  </catalog_product_save_after>
</events>
```

And create a Observer.php in your model folder.

Write your code in that method as below : in Observer.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Yourmodule_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
   public function __construct()
   {
   }
   public function methodName($observer)
   {
         // your code to assign the products to categories
   }
}
?>
```

Refer this link for more : http://www.pierrefay.com/event-observers-magento-tutorial-howto-105

Cheers :-)

Comment: Girish I have a category attribute "dynamic_mapping".If admin select yes then products should be automatically mapped..So need to catch some cageory event related to save.

Comment: I have cutsom category attribute with Yes/No option..While editing the category if admin select that attribute vale to "Yes" then bestseller products should  be automatically mapped to that category...I have all logic...But dnt know which event to use...Plz help me with this.

Comment: Shweta I have written the code above, you can use it. There is a event catelog_product_save_after you have to write your code in the observer method. Do some research on observer